# SLURM : how should I understand the ntasks parameter?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, slurm

I am playing with a cluster using SLURM on AWS. I have defined the following parameters :

```sh
#!/bin/sh
[...]
#SBATCH --ntasks=216
#SBATCH --constraint=c5n.18xlarge
```

Now how should I understand `ntasks` ? What is exactly this parameter ? How does it relate to the number of vCPU? And therefore the number of nodes that will be provisionned ?

AFAIK, it does not correspond to the number of vCPU because I tried to select a multiple of 72 ([c5n.18xlarge](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/c5/) have 72 vCPU) and it did not correspond to the number of EC2 instances provisioned.

I saw I can also use other parameters such as :

```
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=2
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=1
```

but again, the `ntasks` parameter remains unclear to me. For information, I then use the cluster to run an openmpi process using `$SLURM_NTASKS` variable, as advised in an AWS workshop, i.e. :

```sh
mpirun -np $SLURM_NTASKS some_process
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: note that vCPU are in fact the number of threads so CPU cores times threads per CPU core. Information gathered from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instance-optimize-cpu.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Slurm the number of tasks is essentially the number of parallel programs you can start in your allocation. By default, each task can access one CPU (which can be core or thread, depending on config), which can be modified with `--cpus-per-task=#`.

This in itself does not tell you anything about the number of nodes you will get. If you just specify `--ntasks` (or just `-n`), your job will be spread over many nodes, depending on whats available. You can limit this with [`--nodes #min-#max/--nodes #exact`](https://slurm.schedmd.com/sbatch.html#OPT_nodes).
Another way to specify the number of tasks is [`--ntasks-per-node`](https://slurm.schedmd.com/sbatch.html#OPT_ntasks-per-node), which does exactly what is says and is best used in conjunction with `--nodes`. (**not** with `--ntasks`, otherwise it's the max number of tasks per node!)

So, if you want three nodes with 72 tasks (each with the one default CPU), try:

```
#SBATCH --ntasks=216
#SBATCH --nodes=3
#SBATCH --constraint=c5n.18xlarge
```

or:

```
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=72
#SBATCH --nodes=3
#SBATCH --constraint=c5n.18xlarge
```

Comment: How does this differ from setting `--ntasks-per-node=1` *and* `--cpus-per-task=72`?